# tikz - interactive graph with mouse position

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to create a graph interactive with mouse, say if mouse hover to some text label, then highlight the related area. below is a example graph:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1,>=latex]
\foreach \a/\b/\c/\d/\desc [count=\j] in {
    0/0/5/8/box1,
    0/0/5/8/box2,
    1/1/4/7/box3,
    0/0/3/6/box4
}{
    \path (-2,0) ++(0,\j) coordinate (A);
    \draw (\a,\b) rectangle (\c,\d);
    \draw[<-,red] (\a,\b) -- (A) node[anchor=east,pos=1] {\desc};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If mouse hover to box1, it should highlight area (0,0) - (5,8). I know animation support but it's not interactive (control by mouse position).

[image]

Comment: This is possible with the ocgx2 package: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocgx2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example using the ocgx2 package. The file must be compiled twice and requires the PDF reader Acrobat Reader, Foxit Reader or evince. To activate a zone, it is necessary to click on the name of the box.

Many thanks to @AlexG, maintainer of the `ocgx2` package, for specifying in commentary how to make sure that the activation of one layer disables the others with the option `opts={radiobtngrp=myBoxes}}`.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1,>=latex]
\foreach \a/\b/\c/\d/\desc [count=\j] in {
    0/0/5/8/box1,
    0/0/2/4/box2,
    1/1/4/7/box3,
    0/0/3/6/box4
}{
    \path (-2,0) ++(0,\j) coordinate (A);
    \draw (\a,\b) rectangle (\c,\d);
    \begin{scope}[ocg={name=box\j,ref=box\j,status=invisible,opts={radiobtngrp=myBoxes}}]
        \fill[red!30] (\a,\b) rectangle (\c,\d);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[<-,red] (\a,\b) -- (A) node[anchor=east,pos=1,switch ocg=box\j] {\desc};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's great. but when I click the second one, I wish the previous one deselcted. now it will be added over the previous result.

Comment: @lucky1928 Add option `radiobtngrp=myBoxes` to all OCGs: `\begin{scope}[ocg={name=box\j,ref=box\j,status=invisible,opts={radiobtngrp=myBoxes}}]`

Comment: @AlexG Awesome. many thanks!